# Java String Encoding in messenger api request

Tags: java, encoding

I am trying to send Bangladesh language(শাহাবুদদীন), encoded string to facebook messenger API but gives me all "??????????" when displaying. I have tried many methods to encode the string but no luck. I am using com.sun.jersey.api.client to call web service of fb messenger platform. Currently the code for the same is as below:

```
new String(myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

How will I have to encode it?
Do I have to set any header in request for Content-Type or what?

EDIT:

I am sending it to fb messenger api. It is displayed in messenger chat. First creating a  HashMap (params) for request object then as below. The params has the text to be encoded.

```
WebResource _resource = client.resource(_sendMessageURL).queryParam("access_token", <token>);
WebResource.Builder _builder = _resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
String writeValueString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(params);
ClientResponse response = _builder.post(ClientResponse.class, writeValueString);
String _responseBody = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: ‘gives me all "??????????" when displaying.’  What does “displaying” mean?  How are you displaying it?

Comment: Please find the edit. Let me know if any more knowledge is required. @VGR

Comment: Have you tried removing your `new String` statement entirely?  Strings are already capable of representing all characters.  It is rare that re-encoding is necessary.

Comment: Yes that was what implemented previously which was not working

Comment: Where are you seeing "??????????"?  In a browser?

Comment: Its in messenger mobile chat app of facebook